# How to extract h264 and aac elementary stream from an mp4 / mkv using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, h.264, mkv

I could not find a stable and balanced approach to demux the A/V stream and then save it as a playable h264 annex B format video.

Well, I tried the following steps for [shrinkage](http://www.auby.no/files/video_tests/) file.

> gst-launch-0.10  filesrc
>   location=h264_720p_mp_3.1_3mbps_aac_shrinkage.mkv  !   matroskademux !
>   filesink location=abc.h264

-rw-rw-r-- 1 XXX XXX 28697147 Nov  1 10:04 h264_720p_mp_3.1_3mbps_aac_shrinkage.mkv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 XXX XXX 27581733 Nov  1 10:19 abc.h264

a file got saved with "not so smaller" size but is not playable, however the parent container format is playable with the following pipeline

> gst-launch-0.10  filesrc
>   location=h264_720p_mp_3.1_3mbps_aac_shrinkage.mkv  !   matroskademux !
>   h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink

**Questions**
Q1. What are the methods to extract the video ES and Audio ES from different containers using gstreamer ?

Q2.  Q1 using some other methods which always works and/or are easy ?

Comment: Did you try `mkvmerge` to demux?

Comment: From http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html it seems it is for linking two files, not extracting. Am I missing something?

Comment: the demuxer `mkvextract` is part of **mkvtoolnix**.

Comment: any progress done by you ion this question? did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to specify which pad you're interested in. Otherwise you couldn't distinguish the audio ES from the video ES.

The following works on my machine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=example.mkv ! queue ! matroskademux name=dmux dmux.video_0 ! queue ! filesink location=vid.265 dmux.audio_0 ! queue ! filesink location=aud.aac
```

Answer (score 0):

Following all commands works for me. It creates h.264 byte stream file from mp4 video file. Newly created file also played using ffplay or gst-play-1.0

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./VID-20190903-WA0012.mp4 ! qtdemux name=pnkj_demux ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! filesink location=./VID-20190903-WA0012_1.264

gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=./VID-20190903-WA0012.mp4 ! qtdemux name=pnkj_demux ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! filesink location=./VID-20190903-WA0012_2.264

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./VID-20190903-WA0012.mp4 ! qtdemux name=pnkj_demux pnkj_demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! filesink location=./VID-20190903-WA0012_3.264

gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=./VID-20190903-WA0012.mp4 ! qtdemux name=pnkj_demux pnkj_demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! filesink location=./VID-20190903-WA0012_4.264

Comment: Note: Not each .mp4 file have h.264 stream. MP4 is a container may be it has different encoded stream like MPEG-4.